# Roles missing in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, security, docker, upgrade, access-control

I am using Docker to add mongodb 2.6.5 to a host that already had 2.4.9 installed and I am sharing the data directory.

When I run the 2.6.5 (in container) I get permission issues apparently due to changes in 2.6:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-to-database/

But when I try to add a user with role roleAdminAnyDatabase I get  "No role named roleAdminAnyDatabase@admin"

Do I need to migrate the data? What is the best way to do that?

I assume I could start up 2.6.5 with no data files and mongorestore the data from 2.4.9. But, does that mean I cannot run 2.4.9 using that directory anymore?

Comment: Don't fire up a 2.6 server on top of 2.4 data files. That's not a good upgrade path, especially when authentication was used on the 2.4 server. There's [detailed 2.4 -> 2.6 upgrade instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade) as part of the 2.6 release notes.

Comment: Specifically this piece - it got it's own page because it was such a big change: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade-authorization/